# How can I take data from two separated column to be shown in DropDownList using .Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am new student developer in ASP.Net MVC 5. I need to take one data from my two seperated table column in SQL while inserting  but I am taking only one value into my DropDownList. How can I do this? There is not properly info or source according to my research. Does anyone help me ?

Model:

```
public class PersonelModel
    {  
        public int pid { get; set; }
        public string pAd { get; set; }
        public string pSoyad { get; set; }
        public string yonetici { get; set; } 
    }
```

My Add  Method:

```
public ActionResult PersonelAdd()
{

    /*it does not work
     ViewBag.yonetici = new SelectList(db.Personel, "pAd", "pAd" +" "+ "pSoyad");*/

    /*it work*/
    ViewBag.yonetici = new SelectList(db.Personel, "pAd", "pAd");

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PersonelAdd(Personel pModel)
{
    var personel = new Personel();
    personel.pAd = pModel.pAd;
    personel.pSoyad = pModel.pSoyad;
    personel.yonetici = pModel.yonetici;
    /*it works*/
    ViewBag.yonetici = new SelectList(db.Personel, "pAd", "pAd", pModel.yonetici
    );

    // it does not work 
    // ViewBag.yonetici = new SelectList(db.Personel, "pAd", "pAd"+" "+"pSoyad", pModel.yonetici);

    db.Personel.Add(personel);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminUI");
}
```

My form:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.yonetici, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("yonetici", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.yonetici, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SelectList constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_) takes field names (`dataValueField` and `dataTextField`) which have to exist in your model class.

You can add new field to describe what do you want to show as Text (note new `Description` property):

```
public class PersonelModel
{
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public string pAd { get; set; }
    public string pSoyad { get; set; }
    public string yonetici { get; set; }
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return pAd + " " + pSoyad;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can show pAd + pSoyad as Text Value of SelectList:

```
ViewBag.yonetici = new SelectList(db.Personel, "pAd", "Description")
```

Comment: when i tried to add string Descprition value , i am facing an error like " Only assignment,call,increment,decrement, and new object expression can be ysed as a statement." in my PersonelModel.cs. So there is an error.

Comment: it showed "pAd pSoyad" in DropDownList successfully. But while inserting data to database , it is only sending pAd to SQL table. Should [HttpPost] part be for sending pAd + pSoyad ?

Comment: Yep I think you should modify your view to populate whole PersonelModel before sending it to controller. DropDownList sets only one property (valueproperty pAd).